# Loading of asset images in androidTest fails using Picasso/Glide

Tags: android, testing, assets, picasso, android-glide

**Short question**

How can I sucessfully load an asset image in an androidTest with Picasso or Glide?

**Long explaination**

In an UI test I want to invoke my application to load images into an ImageView with certain operations applied to them (e.g. cropping, centering, etc.). To perform the image loading, cropping, etc., I use Picasso. In the UI test I want to verify that after triggering the loading via UI the bitmap attached to the ImageView is exactly what I intended using Picasso, i.e. I’m connecting Picasso and applying the Picasso DSL correctly.

To do that I spin up an androidTest, supplying the images to verify with as assets in `src/androidTest/resources/assets`. I inject `file:///android_asset/$filename` as image filename into my application to have Picasso use the `AssetManager` for loading the image.

Although the application works with regular images stored on the device / in the emulator, the test fails loading the asset images -- the AssetManager reports a FileNotFoundException:

```
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: australia.jpg
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAsset(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:744)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:721)
        at com.squareup.picasso.AssetRequestHandler.load(AssetRequestHandler.java:45)
        at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206)
        at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.get(RequestCreator.java:396)
```

By the way, using Glide leads to the same FileNotFoundException.

I’ve set up a [small instrumented test `AssetTest.kt`](https://github.com/cee-dee/android-testing/blob/image-asset-loading-with-picasso-in-androidtest/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/AssetTest.kt) to analyze and showcase the problem. Please follow the link to view it completely on GitHub.

```java
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class AssetTest {

    private lateinit var activityScenario: ActivityScenario<TasksActivity>
    private val filename = "victoria-priessnitz-KBIui3I44SY-unsplash.jpg"
    // NOTE: the tests show the same behavior regardless of whether the activity is launched or not
    private val enableActivityUsage = true

    @Before
    fun launchActivity() {
        if (enableActivityUsage) {
            activityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(TasksActivity::class.java)
        }
    }

    @After
    fun shutdownActivity() {
        if (enableActivityUsage) {
            activityScenario.close()
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun loadingAssetImageWithInstrumentationContextSucceeds() {
        val ctx = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
        val inputStream = ctx.resources.assets.open(filename)
        val bytes = inputStream.readBytes()
        assertEquals(1903567, bytes.size)
    }

    @Test(expected = FileNotFoundException::class)
    fun loadingAssetImageWithInstrumentationTargetContextFails() {
        val targetCtx = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        val inputStream = targetCtx.resources.assets.open(filename)
        inputStream.readBytes()
    }

    @Test(expected = FileNotFoundException::class)
    fun loadingAssetImageWithInstrumentationTargetContextsApplicationContextFails() {
        val targetCtx = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext.applicationContext
        val inputStream = targetCtx.resources.assets.open(filename)
        inputStream.readBytes()
    }

    // NOTE: when not using the test orchestrator to separate tests, this tests may fail
    // because the execution shows the same behavior as with targetContext
    @Test(expected = NullPointerException::class)
    fun picassoFailsWithNullPointerExceptionWhenUsingContext() {
        val uri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/$filename")
        // synchronous image loading cannot be performed in main thread
        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
        try {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(uri)
                    .get()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // sometimes Android Studio does not display callstacks in debugger
            println(e.message)
            throw e
        }
    }

    @Test(expected = FileNotFoundException::class)
    fun picassoFailsWithExceptionInAssetManagerOpenWhenUsingTargetContext() {
        val uri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/$filename")
        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        try {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(uri)
                    .get()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // sometimes Android Studio does not display callstacks in debugger
            println(e.message)
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

I observed the following:

1. The test `loadingAssetImageWithInstrumentationContextSucceeds` can load the asset while and `loadingAssetImageWithInstrumentationTargetContextFails` cannot load the asset -- regardless of being run in an ActivityScenario or not. I conclude that the assets are stored in an APK accessible from context, but not in an APK accessible from targetContext. Unfortunately I know no way to look inside the referenced APKs since the Device File Explorer fails to open them in /data/app.
2. The test `picassoFailsWithNullPointerExceptionWhenUsingContext` shows that using `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context` lets Picasso fail due to a null pointer exception. I could see in the Picasso builder internals that Picasso does not directly make use of the supplied context, but calls `ContextImpl::getApplicationContext` -- where `mPackageInfo.getApplication` is `null`:

```java
    @Override
    public Context getApplicationContext() {
        return (mPackageInfo != null) ?
                mPackageInfo.getApplication() : mMainThread.getApplication();
    }
```

3. The test `picassoFailsWithExceptionInAssetManagerOpenWhenUsingTargetContext` shows that using `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext` will not cause a null pointer exception, but lead to a `FileNotFoundException` from the `AssetManager` as mentioned above. I conclude that the APK attached tot hat `targetContext.applicationContext` does not contain the assets.
4. I’m rather confused about all the different Context existing on created when spinning up Activities.

**But coming back to the question:**

There certainly are other (more expensive) ways to test my scenario, but I think there should be a working way to just load an asset with Picasso in an instrumented test.